# Schedule azure data lake analytics u-sql jobs

Tags: azure-automation, azure-data-lake, u-sql

Is there any way to automate data lake analytics jobs and run them on some schedule?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is recommended to use Azure Data Factory.  Take a look at [this blog post](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/creating-big-data-pipelines-using-azure-data-lake-and-azure-data-factory/) as an example.

Answer (score 0):

1. If you are not expecting your data to be scheduled and you want to run a job based on a event then you can submit a U-SQL job using PS commands.
2. You can still schedule your PS script using the Automation Account and Schedule it when every you want it to run.
3. I personally don't prefer to use ADF for event based runs as it was designed to be to run scheduled tasks.